# Is dynamic_cast slower than static_cast?

Tags: c++

Since `dynamic_cast` does run-time type checking and `static_cast` does not incur the overhead of this type-safety( if you can call it overhead), I was wondering if the performance of `dynamic_cast` is slower than `static_cast`?

Comment: Why do you assume `static_cast` does not incur run time overhead?

Comment: `dynamic_cast` *may* incur runtime overhead. It doesn't *have* to.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux as OP asks about static vs dynamic he/she most probably means usage on pointer to class as you cannot do `dynamic_cast` from double to int.

Comment: Put it this way: if using static_cast or dynamic_cast both produce compilable code, neglecting run-time behaviour, then static_cast is never slower.

Comment: `dynamic_cast` and `static_cast` perform different operations. Comparing the runtime characteristics of different things does not make sense. If you need to use a `static_cast`, then do. If your code requires a `dynamic_cast` then likewise, use that.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude but it does do type checking at run-time, right? Isn't that overhead or

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux because it does not do type checking or any extra things(compared to dynamic_cast), right`?

Comment: If you see e.g. [this `dynamic_cast` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) you will see that there is only one case where it explicitly mentions a "run-time check". There are many cases where the compiler can perform the cast without the need for any run-time code to be executed.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude hmm okay then. But in that case, it IS slower than static_cast, correct`?

Comment: In *that* case then yes it will incur a *small* run-time overhead. How much? I don't know, but probably small enough to not really be measurable unless you do thousands (or maybe even tens of thousands) of such casts every second. As always *measure*, *benchmark* and *profile*.

Comment: Did you mean `reinterpret_cast` instead of `static_cast`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude okay makes makes sense now but how come the type checking happens at run-time? I mean the types are specified before run-time?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude if you or just someone could please answer my comment above, it would be fantastic because then I would not really have any more confusion about this topic

Comment: The types may not be known until runtime. Consider an interface that takes a pointer to a base class: `void foo(Base*)`. Now you call `foo` with instances of derived classes `Derived1` and `Derived2`. Also consider, that class instances of `Derived1` and `Derived2` are constructed at runtime as the result of deserializing a network stream. If you `dynamic_cast` in `foo` it requires a check that can only be performed at runtime.

Comment: @IInspectable wow thank you! Now I can see the point. But 1. Are class instances in general constructed at runtime or was it just in your example? 2. I know this may be out of context, but what does "deserializing a network stream" a network stream? Thanks again man! Much appreciated

Comment: Class instances can be constructed at compile time as well as runtime. The important part about the example I picked is, that the data used to construct class instances is only available at runtime. If that data were available at compile time, a compiler could analyze code and data flow, and eliminate the runtime type checks. [Wikipedia has an entry on serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization).